# Convert Json Format

Tags: json

I have a json file with the content:

```
{  
    "id" : 10,  
    "name" : "book1",  
    "user" : "john",  
    "chapters" : [
        {  
            "chaptername" : "chapter1",  
            "content" : "index"  
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert it with a nice format (e.g. tree format or table). Does any know some good java packages for it?

Thanks

Comment: Although JSON provides a defined way of describing data, the data structures it describes are purely arbitrary. Also arbitrary is the format to which you wish to convert. How could a lone generic library convert from one arbitrary structure to another?

Answer (score 1):

It wont work like magic, you can use either Gson or Jackson to map the json into java types or objects, from there you can do whatever you want with those json's mapped as objects.

For example you will have the following blueprint for this:

```
public class YourJson {

private int id;
private String name, user;
private Chapter[] chapter;

...
// Getters and setters ommitted
...
}

public class Chapter {
private String chaptername;
private String content;
...
// Getters and setters ommitted
...
}
```

Once you have added jackson as a library in your project, you can use jackson's object mapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourJson jsonAsObject = objectMapper.readValue(yourJsonString, YourJson.class);
```

from there you can access the properties

```
System.out.println(jsonAsObject.getId());
```

Comment: I would recommend JAXB ;)

Comment: I haven' tried JAXB, but i will take a look :D!

Comment: It's easy man! All you need is: 1 class, 1 annotation, 1 xml and execute unmarshall. Best regards!